# Rails - tinymce-rails-imageupload configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I'm using rails 4 and tinymce 4 and also the gem [tinymce-rails-imageupload](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload)

I've gotten the gem installed with little trouble as follows:

config/tinymce.yml

```
theme: "modern"
toolbar1: bold italic | link uploadimage | undo redo | fontselect | forecolor | code | 
plugins:
  - link
  - uploadimage
  - textcolor
  - code
```

The problem is that when I try to upload an image from my computer I get the message:

> Bad response from server

and my server logs say:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/tinymce_assets")
```

Is there a way to get around this without creating a new controller/table for tinymce? I really don't need to store the images. If not, could anyone point me towards a good tutorial for setting up the controller? There's an example on the gems README but my knowledge of RoR is not strong enough for me to figure out how to pass in all the required information by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, there is little way for you to get around this issue. You do not necessarily need to create a new "Table" in your database for tinymce, but you will either need a new controller with the create action or you could probably latch on the action on an existing controller, but that is a bit messy.

Here's a github repository that has the source code for the demo (the author of the gem wrote the demo, so it's good), it has pretty much everything you need : https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload-demo. It uses Paperclip to do the actual upload of the images (which does require the table).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks for the critique Mike. 

SoSimple, why are you using imageupload if you do not need to store the images? I would wager that you do if you are using it.

Comment: @tyrantkhan You're right, I realised that I do actually need to store the images. I thought I would be able to get away without it. I'm having a look at the source code for the demo now, thanks for pointing it out.